# Need Suggestion for Picking the Right Solvent for Column Chromatography

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, chromatography

I've completed my reactions, and based on the stoichiometry and TLC analysis, I think my mixture should contain 3-4 compounds:

1. Ethyl gallate (my product)
2. Gallic acid (the reagent/starting material)
3. Dicyclohexylurea (by-product from my reaction)
4. Pyridine (catalyst that I used)

Here's my TLC result (please look carefully there are 3-4 spots):

- **Spot No. 1** = gallic acid
- **Spot No. 2** = my successful mixture
- **Spot No. 3** = my semi-successful mixture (it's not completely successful because there are still pretty much gallic acid remaining)
- **Solvent A** = chloroform : methanol => 100 : 1
- **Solvent B** = n-hexane : ethyl acetate => 1 : 3

[image: TLC]

Based on that, I must do purification by doing column chromatography. However, I've very little experience in doing column chromatography and I'm unsure about the appropriate solvent for my column.

**My questions:**

1. Based on the TLC result, which solvent is more suitable for my column chromatography to separate compounds? And could you explain why it's more suitable, please?
2. Do you have any suggestions regarding the mixture ratio for my solvent system? (like should I lower the ethyl acetate etc.)

Feel free to add other suggestions/advice that you've for me.

**Note:**
I also don't know which spot on the TLC plate corresponds to my product.

Comment: Your product is most likely the high running spot on system B. Try running another tlc of 1:1 hexane/EtOAc which should bring your gallic acid SM down to approx baseline and your product to Rf 0.3-0.4

Comment: I see, but could you share your thoughts on my TLC result using chloroform:methanol (1:1)? What are the issues with that TLC? Is my product spot (Rf) too low?"

Comment: Try another tlc with a bit more MeOH (2%) to try to separate out the product. Note that the DCHU does not really stain with most reagents

Comment: Okay, I kind of get it now. Regarding DCHU not staining, could I use KMNO4 or Ninhydrin to make the DCHU spot appear?

Comment: @Jonathan You wrote you used 1 Percent methanol. 1:1 would be 50 and at this point most compounds will not show any retention. It would make sense to run a stepwise gradient from 10 to maybe 50 Percent EtAc to purify your product. You can check fractions by running them on a TLC and check which fractions will be pure and and separated from the starting material/ side product.

Comment: @raptorlane I agree. I think a gradient hexane/EtOAc ending with neat EtOAc column is likely the way to go.  Ninhydrin will not visualise DCHU, KMnO4 + heating the plate may do but most likely as a white spot against the background

Comment: I see, I think I could try that. Thanks for your suggestions/advice.

Comment: @raptorlane I have an additional question. The solvent I use to dilute my mixture and starting materials, such as gallic acid, is THF. Is it okay to use THF too as a solvent "for diluting my compounds" for TLC and column chromatography? Because my mixture texture is kind of like a paste.

Comment: I would use DCM as a solvent for dilution on TLCs, because it evaporates fast. Before you put your compound on the column, I would evaporate all volatiles as good as possible. THF might cause problems in the purification process. For full pyridine removal you might put the sample on lyophilizer or remove the major amount by water/DCM workup (some acid will pull the pyridine in the water phase).

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought the pyridine could be remove through the column too. It seems I was wrong all this time.

One thing I forgot to mention is that gallic acid is insoluble in DCM. So, what should I do?